# Cannot install fuerte from source because kforge.ros.org is down

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, kforge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
ardrone@raspberrypi ~ $ rosdep install -ay --os=debian:squeeze

ERROR: Rosdep experienced an error: Failed to load a rdmanifest from https://kforge.ros.org/rosrelease/viewvc/sourcedeps/yaml-cpp/yaml-cpp-0.2.5.rdmanifest: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
Please go to the rosdep page [1] and file a bug report with the stack trace below.
[1] : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep

rosdep version: 0.11.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 136, in rosdep_main
    exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 345, in _rosdep_main
    return _package_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 435, in _package_args_handler
    return command_handlers[command](lookup, packages, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 619, in command_install
    uninstalled, errors = installer.get_uninstalled(packages, implicit=options.recursive, verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/installers.py", line 405, in get_uninstalled
    resolutions, errors = self.lookup.resolve_all(resources, installer_context, implicit=implicit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 391, in resolve_all
    self.resolve(rosdep_key, resource_name, installer_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 480, in resolve
    resolution = installer.resolve(rosdep_args_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/source.py", line 216, in resolve
    raise InvalidData(str(ex))
InvalidData: Failed to load a rdmanifest from https://kforge.ros.org/rosrelease/viewvc/sourcedeps/yaml-cpp/yaml-cpp-0.2.5.rdmanifest: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199861/cannot-install-fuerte-from-source-because-kforge.ros.org-is-down/) by [Alvar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21018/alvar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

kforge.ros.org was turned off when Willow Garage shut down. It doesn't exist any more.

ROS Fuerte is no longer supported. You should look for a newer version of ROS for your Raspberry Pi. Many users have reported successfully installing ROS Groovy, Hydro and Indigo on their Raspberry Pi.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0